# How to use module.modulemap for importing objC framework inside swift framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I am creating a Swift framework
I have to use an Objective-C framework inside Swift framework.

We cant use bridging header since target is a Swift framework not a Swift application.
Instead I use module.modulemap file:

```
module ObjSDK
{
    header "ObjSDK.framework/Headers/classA.h"
    export *
}
```

Later in config file set:

```
SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS = $(SRCROOT)/
MODULEMAP_PRIVATE_FILE = $(SRCROOT)/module.modulemap
```

Then build success.

After that when try to use `classA` in swift class under swift framework, it failed.

Please suggest any if any missing steps or any other solution.

Comment: can you specify further about  _"when try to use ... it failed"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Please double check following steps again

- Add your Objective C framework under **Linked Frameworks** and Libraries
  in your Swift framework project
- Then create an **Aggregate** target to the project and when crating that, give the Objective C framework name as the **Product Name**
- Then go to Build Phase and add a **New Run Script Phase**
- Content of the script should be similar to below. But replace the *AnujaObjectiveCFramework* with your Objective C framework name

> if [ -d "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/AnujaObjectiveCFramework" ]; then echo
>   "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/AnujaObjectiveCFramework directory already
>   exists, so skipping the rest of the script." exit 0 fi
>
> mkdir -p "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/AnujaObjectiveCFramework" cat 
>   << EOF >
>   "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/AnujaObjectiveCFramework/module.modulemap"
>   module AnujObjcModule { header
>   "${PROJECT_DIR}/AnujaObjectiveCFramework.framework/Headers/AnujaObjectiveCFramework.h"
>   export * } EOF

- Then build the Aggregate framework by selecting it from the list of scheme
- Now you have to include that built framework as a **Target dependency** of your Swift framework.
- Now is the time for you to build your Swift framework.

### Additional details :

- Once you refer that Swift framework in your original project and ended up with ***dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/*** error, then you have to modify your Swift frameworks **Installation Directory** attribute with the value **@EXECUTABLE_PATH/../Frameworks** and then add your frameworks inside the Frameworks Group in your Swift project.
- Make sure the classes and functions that you need to access inside the Swift framework has **public** or **open** access identifiers according to your needs.
- Make sure to add necessary header files inside your bridging header in your Objective C framework.